# Problem with `plot` option for `gdraw` in MetaPost

Tags: plot, metapost

I have the following problem with MetaPost and `graph` package for it. So I have a source:

```
input graph;

beginfig(1)
    draw begingraph(16cm, 2cm);
        gdraw "a.txt" plot "+";
        endgraph;
endfig;

bye;
```

It works perfectly if I remove `plot`. But using `plot` gives the following output.

```
This is MetaPost, version 1.803 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit)
(mpost.mp (C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004) )
(C:/Graph/MyGraph.mp
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/graph.mp
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/marith.mp
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/string.mp))
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/format.mp
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/string.mp)
(C:/Program Files/MiKTeX 2.9/metapost/base/texnum.mp)))
>> "+"
! Improper `addto'.
<to be read again>
                   ;
<to be read again>
                   setbounds
Gsetb_->setbounds
                 .currentpicture.to
<argument> ...w_.q.endfor.else:Gdrw_("+")fi.Gsetb_
                                                  .origin..cycle
image->...ture;currentpicture:=nullpicture;(TEXT2)
                                                  ;currentpicture.endgroup
hide->exitif.numeric.begingroup(TEXT0)
                                      ;endgroup;
<argument> ...:Gdrw_("+")fi.Gsetb_.origin..cycle))
                                                  fi
Gwithlist_->(TEXT0)
                   ;Gpostdr_;
<to be read again>
                   ;
l.6          gdraw "a.txt" plot "+";

?
[1] )
1 output file written: MyGraph.1
Transcript written on MyGraph.log.
```

It does not depend on character I use for `plot`. Also `plot btex $\bullet$ etex` causes the same error. Any idea?

Comment: Did the following answer work? Please make us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As fpast mentioned `"..."` should not be allowed after `plot`. And my problem with `btex ... etex` was rather stupid, I've used `-tex=latex` option for `mpost` while as far as you can see above I have not provided `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a (not serious) `a.txt` file with the following lines inside:

```
1cm 0
2cm 1cm
3cm 2cm
```

And the following works for me:

```
input graph;

beginfig(1)
    draw begingraph(16cm, 2cm);
        gdraw "a.txt" plot (btex $+$ etex);
        endgraph;
endfig;

bye;
```

Result:

[image]

Judging by the complementary error messages I've obtained with your coding, It seems that a picture is expected after the `plot` command. Hence my use of `btex ... etex` which results in a picture, and not `"..."`, which is a string. The parentheses around `btex ... etex` are probably mandatory here because otherwise it would be the `btex` token which would be taken as argument.

Comment: Yes, you are write, `"..."` should not be allowed.